# Flattening a 3d triangle

Tags: math, language-agnostic, 3d

I would like to write a function that takes a 3d triangle (as 3 points (vector3ds)) and returns a 2d triangle (as 3 points (vector2ds)):

When given a 3d triangle, it should return the 2 dimensional coordinates of its points as they lie on its plane. (By 'its plane' I mean the plane that all three points lie on).

I can think a long winded way todo this:

- rotate the triangle until its normal is equal to +z (0,0,1), then construct a  triangle from the (x, y) coords of each point.

I cant help but think there must be an easier way to achieve the same thing.

*If posting code examples please try not to use Greek alphabet. Some pseudo code in a C/java style language would be ideal.*

Comment: how are the triangles to be represented? i.e. you hand me a 3-d triangle, but what is that? is it a bunch of 3-space points?

Comment: The answer is ambiguous.  You have to specify some arbitrary coordinate system in the plane of the triangle.  You can always choose this coordinate system in a way that the answer is (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1).

Comment: what's the desired origin of this plane?  If not one of the vertices then it has to be some other arbitrary point.

Comment: What's wrong with the Greek alphabet?

Comment: @root45 maybe it's a protest against their fiscal situation?

Comment: @Yoel points. Alnitak the origin can be anything, so long as the points are the correct distance from each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comments I infer that you can choose the coordinate system of the plane in an arbitrary way, as long as the Euclidean metric of this coordinate system is the same as the metric induced by the Euclidean metric of your three-dimensional coordinate system.  (That is, Euclidean distances will stay the same.)

One possible solution:

```
x0' = 0
y0' = 0

x1' = sqrt((x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2 + (z1 - z0)^2)
y1' = 0

x2' = ((x1 - x0) * (x2 - x0) + 
       (y1 - y0) * (y2 - y0) + 
       (z1 - z0) * (z2 - z0)) / x1'
y2' = sqrt((x2 - x0)^2 + (y2 - y0)^2 + (z2 - z0)^2 - x2'^2)
```

Comment: you appear to be using the dot product to work out `cos(theta)` - doesn't this run the risk of the resulting triangle having its normal 'flipped' (not withstanding that the new coordinate system is somewhat arbitrary) ?

Comment: @Alnitak Why should it? A triangle's angle is always < 180 degrees.

Comment: @ChristianRau because it could also be -180 < theta < 0 (i.e. if v3 is on the "right" of the vector from v1 to v2).

Comment: @Alnitak:  The only condition I was able to infer from the OP's comments was that the coordinate system should be chosen in a way that preserves the Euclidean distance.  Conservation of orientation was not requested.

Comment: @SvenMarnach indeed I don't think it matters too much, as the orientation is somewhat arbitrary anyway.  I only queried it since I had intentionally used the cross product sine rule rather than the dot product cosine rule specifically to mitigate the effect.

Answer (score 4):

There is no singular answer to this problem.

The plane in which the triangle sits has no defined origin, and no defined orientation.

The best you can do is define one of the vertices as the origin, and one of the edges laying along the X axis:

```
v1 = (0, 0)
```

You will need to calculate vectors **`A`** (i.e. `v2 - v1`) and **`B`** (i.e. `v3 - v1`).

Vertex 2 will then be at:

```
v2 = (|A|, 0)
```

The position of vertex 3 can be worked out by using the [*vector cross product rule*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), e.g.:

```
A x B = |A| * |B| sin(theta)
```

So, work out `A x B` and from that you can work out the sine of the angle *theta* between **`A`** and **`B`**:

```
sin(theta) = | A x B | / (|A| * |B|)
```

Vertex 3 is then at coordinates:

```
v3 = |B| (cos(theta), sin(theta))
```

You can take advantage of `cos(theta) = sqrt(1 - sin(theta) ^ 2)` to avoid any inverse trig operations.

You should also see that `|B| sin(theta)` is just `| A x B | / | A |`

Comment: You can also take advantage of `|B| * cos(theta) = (A . B) / |A|` and don't even need a `sqrt`. So `v3 = (A.B, |AxB|) / |A|`.

Comment: 8 years ago, erf, it's quite long, i was asking myself if, following your suggestion, there is an elegant solution to convert a 2D point back to the 3D space

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac you have the same problem in reverse - how do you define the "correct" plane in which that triangle sits, and its position within that plane.  This is why algorithms that map 2D pictures back into 3D require _multiple_ pictures from different angles that between them provide sufficient additional information to infer that.

Comment: My question is simplier i think. Imagine that i'm using you're solution to get 2D triangle from a 3D one. 2D geometry allow me to apply 2D algorithms to generate 2D points (let's say [Poisson Disc Sampling](https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/), how, from those points, get their respective 3D points? How to apply the inverse transformation you suggested?

Comment: By decomposing the 2D point M' this way https://josephm.fr/misc/triangles-3d-to-2d.html i should be able to convert back to 3D, any opinion on that solution? Must find how to retrieve kb & kc...

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac you can't - the 3D to 2D transformation destroys information that cannot be reconstructed from the known 2D coordinates.  It's like being given A*B = 24 and being asked to say what A and B were.   You can't, because there's multiple possibilities.

Comment: @Alnitak i'm sorry if i'm not clear, i think we do not understand each other because of a detail, which is evident to me but may be not to you, when i'm talking about 3D point in 3D space i'm talking about points that are already on the surface of the triangle. Imagine that i want to populate a given triangle (3D) with some nodes that are on the surface. It would be easier to use 2 algorithms to place thoses nodes, and then to convert their positions in 3D spaces. It's feasible right? ([I'm trying to achieve this](https://josephm.fr/misc/populate3D.jpg))

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac for any triangle BAC (whether 2D or 3D) points _within_ that triangle can be found as u*(BA) + v*(CA) where 0 <= u <= 1, 0 <= v <= 1, and 0 <= u + v <= 1.   There's no need for any complicated 3D to 2D to 3D transformations.

Comment: @Alnitak May be not, if i'm trying to convert 3D to 2D coordinantes it's because of this algorithm [Poisson Disc](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3) [original print](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf), where, to allow O(n) time complexity, a grid is used to for sample lookup.

Comment: @JosephMerdrignac I think you can just pick values for `u` and `v` (i.e. 2 dimensions) and reject those that fail the bounds checks.